# Term for offering something just out of reach?

Tags: meaning, phrases, phrase-requests, idioms, idiom-requests

Is there a word or phrase that describes a situation where you are intentionally offering something to someone who can't attain it?

Example: I'll give you my seat for a million dollars.

Comment: "dangling something over your head"

Comment: Not a direct answer, but I will note that this scenario is literally the same one as for the expression "sour grapes".

Comment: For most people, a chair in exchange for a million dollars doesn't represent an offer that is "just out of reach". It is unobtainable or might as well be.

Answer (score 22):

Look up **tantalize**. It is defined at [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tantalize) as

> Torment or tease (someone) with the sight or promise of something that is unobtainable.

Comment: It derives from  [Tantalus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tantalus), a character in Greek mythology who was consigned to [Tartarus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tartarus), a place of suffering for the wicked after death, where "he was made to stand in a pool of water beneath a fruit tree with low branches, with the fruit ever eluding his grasp, and the water always receding before he could take a drink", so that he could never slake his hunger nor thirst.

Comment: I'm not sure this is quite accurate, at least not given the example OP used. It is a great word for "tease", though.

Comment: @C.M Weimer, see also the definition for [tantalize](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/tantalize) at dictionary.com: "to torment with, or as if with, the sight of something desired but out of reach; tease by arousing expectations that are repeatedly disappointed."

Comment: @moonpoint Yeah, that's something like "tease." I'm just not sure that OP's example really meant that. But that might just be a bad example.

Answer (score 8):

Many writers have referred to...

> [*(dangling) a mythical carrot*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a%20mythical%20carrot%22)

...but when I stop to think about it, I'm pretty sure the [*donkey - carrot - stick*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=donkey%20carrot%20stick&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB712GB712&espv=2&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1kNe45_TSAhVHPBQKHYwvAdYQ7AkIJg&biw=1249&bih=823) reference isn't to some kind of mythical fairy tale. I'm sure you really *can* get a donkey to traipse round a treadmill all day if you hang a real (non-mythical) carrot off a stick, just in front of him.

So that carrot can't be *exactly* "mythical" (besides which, if the realworld treadmill donkey *never* got a carrot, I'm sure he'd give up after a while; donkeys aren't *that* dumb). But it has been used.

Comment: Yeah, mythical is definitely the wrong adjective here. "Proverbial" would be more appropriate.

Comment: Well, probably not all day. They'll catch on eventually, and they have a... *proverbial* attitude.

Comment: This is commonly phrased as "carrot on a stick".

Comment: @Dancrumb: But as I tried to point out, the *proverbial* carrot is an inducement/bribe that's not only *offered* - it's usually *delivered*, sooner or later. By contrast, a *mythical* carrot can be quite naturally understood as something which might appear tempting, but *you ain't never gonna get it!*

Comment: I'd love to see https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ie2uP.gif in your answer.

Comment: @vickyace: But it ***is**!* Presumably for the same reason(s) as you, I thought in terms of a *visual image*, so I specifically made my ***second*** link to a google search for images. Your cartoon one is currently second in the list of results as returned to me just now, where the *first* one is an actual photo of a real donkey + carrot + stick. I must say the cartoon donkey with goofy teeth looks a lot dumber than the real one, but to be honest I'm not even sure that "donkeys are dumb" is a necessary implication of the allusion (i.e. - *anyone* hoping for the proverbial carrot must be dumb).

Comment: Your link is where I got it from in the first place. It is just that, a photographic aid makes any answer more.,well, a sight for sore eyes. :) Pardon my whimsy. I'm still a kid.

Comment: @vickyace: I can get a bit irritated when people post answers with (sometimes *multiple*) images that don't really add anything to the text (i.e. - they're just "attention grabbers"). In this specific case I'm open-minded as to whether including that pic would enhance, detract, or not make much difference. Perhaps you'd like to raise the matter on meta, and maybe cite this answer as one where you'd like to know whether the majority of ELU users think a picture could be worth more than my [considerably less than a thousand] words! Seriously - I'd be interested to know too. :)

Comment: (Pardon my "seriousness" - I've almost forgotten how good it was to be whimsical! :)

Comment: Whoa! You just lighted the light bulb in my head. I am always scared when it comes to posting stuff on meta but that donkey in the photo is too cute to be left out. I'll fight for him.

Answer (score 1):

**Ask for the moon** is an idiom meaning to ask for something that is unobtainable.

> He may as well have asked me for the moon. I was never going to get that chair.

This is related to other *moon* idioms:
*Promise the moon*: to offer something that's impossible.

> Right now I'm so tired that I would promise the moon to be able to sit in that chair!

*Cry at/for the moon*: make an outlandish or unreasonable request, especially one that is unlikely to be fulfilled.

> If he thinks he can get out of that chair, he's crying at the moon.

(Idioms from [The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/moon))